# Mapping domain to a directory (not a site) in IIS7

Tags: iis, iis-7, domain, bindings

I recently set up my own server, where I've since installed DotNetNuke in its own "site". Now, I want to map multiple domains to that DotNetNuke instance, using the child portals functionality. Thus, I want to map a domain to a directory, rather than to the site root.

I've found the Bindings setup for the site, but I don't think a similar thing exists for directories. However, I know that this is somehow possible, as I've previously done this when my sites were hosted by GoDaddy, although I did it through the GoDaddy hosting control panel.

**How can I map a domain to a directory?** *Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with traditional bindings on IIS. Domains can only be bound to sites.

It IS possible with a [Reverse Proxy](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite), which IIS does support. There are a [lot of questions here already](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/iis+reverse-proxy) on how to do a reverse proxy with IIS - they may point you in the right direction.